# Datatables Add Row Below Specific Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using datatables, looking to create an addRowBelowIndex() function. My brain is pretty frazzled with this one because I'm not really sure how their indices are handled.

I'm working on a solution I found from 5 years ago: http://jsfiddle.net/mLh08nyg/

```
$("#example").on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
var currentPage = table.page();

//insert a test row
count++;
table.row.add([count, count, count, count, count]).draw();

//move added row to desired index (here the row we clicked on)
var index = table.row(this).index(),
    rowCount = table.data().length-1,
    insertedRow = table.row(rowCount).data(),
    tempRow;

for (var i=rowCount;i>index;i--) {
    tempRow = table.row(i-1).data();
    table.row(i).data(tempRow);
    table.row(i-1).data(insertedRow);
}     
//refresh the page
table.page(currentPage).draw(false);
});
```

Which adds a new row ABOVE a specific index, but changing the arithmetic to how I think it should work, fails to work so I'm obviously not understanding core concept.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the suspect line:

```
for (var i=rowCount;i>index;i--)
```

Changing this to

```
for (var i=rowCount;i>index+1;i--)
```

makes it perform the desired behavior. Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f1n4db65/5/).

**So why does this work?** Essentially, what the code performs is a series of swaps, starting from the last entry of the table (the table row at index `rowCount`), which where we inserted our new row, and ending at the row that we clicked on (the table row at index `index`). Note that `index` was calculated with `table.row(this).index()`, where `this` is the DOM element that triggered the `click` event listener.

In each swap, we are swapping our newly inserted row with the row directly above it.

So in the first iteration of the loop, where we start at the last row, this is what we are explicitly doing.

```
tempRow = table.row(i-1).data(); // Save the second to last row to a temporary variable
table.row(i).data(tempRow); // Set the last row to the temporary variable
table.row(i-1).data(insertedRow); // Set the second to the last row as our inserted row
```

After this first iteration, we have changed the end of our table from this:

```
...
original 3rd to last row
original 2nd to last row
original last row
>newly inserted row<
```

to this:

```
...
original 3rd to last row
original 2nd to last row
>newly inserted row<        << swapped
original last row           << swapped
```

So we keep performing this swap on rows `i` and `i-1`, until our newly created row reaches the row that we clicked. In the original code, our last iteration is when `i` is 1 greater than `index`. Therefore, `i-1` in that iteration is the position of our clicked row. Since we are swapping our inserted row with our original row at `i-1`, the new row is inserted ABOVE our clicked row. To insert the new row BELOW our clicked row, we can just end this loop one iteration earlier, so we are never swapping our new row with our original clicked row.

Note that with any type of ordering, this method will not work, as rows will automatically be sorted once they are inserted, so the swaps won't work as intended.